# JTables ,How to insert data in Jtable from a text file

Tags: java, swing, jtable

Hey I don't have enough knowledge on `JTables`, How to insert data in `JTables` by the way I entered the data in my table but I don't know why the column names not appear in my table.

Here's my code:

```
public class tab {
    public tab() {
        initComponents();

    }

    public void initComponents() {
        JFrame fr = new JFrame("Score Card");

        JScrollPane pane = new JScrollPane();
        fr.setSize(500, 350);
        JTable scoreTab = new JTable(5, 4);
        DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(1, 4);
        // model.setColumnIdentifiers(new Object[]{"No","Name","Score","Date"});

        scoreTab.setModel(new javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel(

        new Object[][] { { 1, 2, 2 },

        }, new String[] { "Name", "Score", "Date" }));
        pane.setViewportView(scoreTab);
        fr.add(scoreTab);
        fr.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        fr.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        fr.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new tab();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add `JScrollPane` to the `jframe`

```
fr.add(pane);
```

you are directly adding jtable to the frame <strike>`fr.add(scoreTab);`</strike>

if you add a table without jscrollpane you have to add headers separately.

Comment: will  u please tell me how to dynamically input the data in table,Actually i want to read data from text file and then put it intothe table plz give some hint it means alot to me

Comment: @UmerAli you can read file then you can create model after you finish you can apply model to the table. another way is to create table then read file and add row by row.using `insertRow(Vector v);` method.for example see this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22371720/how-to-add-row-dynamically-in-jtable

Comment: see this question .http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22371720/how-to-add-row-dynamically-in-jtable.