# Appending a new row to a JTable at runtime

Tags: java, swing

I am developing a Java application that uses a JTable. I want to allow the user to enter data in a JTable that can later be printed or saved. The issues is: Suppose the user has entered some data and the cursor is on the last cell of the row in a table (I have uploaded an image-suppose the cursor is on the highlighted cell).How do I make it in such a way that when a user presses the Enter Button(Keyboard button) the application will add/append a new row that is empty to the table so that the user can fill in other data.
[Attachment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7oRAd.png)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add row dynamically in JTable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22371720/how-to-add-row-dynamically-in-jtable)

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
  JTable table = new JTable();
  DefaultTableModel tblModel = new DefautlTableModel(0,0);

  table.setModel(tblModel);



  //an action or click then you should run this code


  tblModel.addRow(new Object[]{""});
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your help. I did what you suggested and it worked perfect.

Comment: I have another problem. How can i get row index in JTable from KeyEvent .

Comment: public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
         if(e.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_CTRL){// which key is pressed. for example control key 
            JTable.getSelectedRow();
         }
      }

Answer (score 0):

```
    DefaultTableModel tbm = (DefaultTableModel) jTable1.getModel();
    Vector rowData = null;
    tbm.addRow(rowData);
```